# How to extract relevant phrases from sentences regarding a particular topic using Neural networks?

Tags: python, text, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have training data as two columns
1.'Sentences'
2.'Relevant_text' (text in this column is a subset of text in the column 'Sentences')

I tried training a RNN with LSTM directly treating 'Sentences' as input and 'Relevant_text' and output but the results were disappointing.

I want to know how to approach this type of problem? Does this kind of problem have a name? Which models should I explore?

Answer (score 2):

If the target text is the subset of the input text, then, I believe, this problem can be solved as a tagging problem: make your neural network for each word predict whether it is "relevant" or not.

On the one hand, the problem of taking a text and selecting its subset that best reflects its meaning is called [extractive summarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization#Extraction-based_summarization), and has lots of solutions, from the well known unsupervised [textRank](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/11/introduction-text-summarization-textrank-python/) algorithm to complex BERT-based neural models.

On the other hand, technically your problem is just binary token-wise classification: you label each token (word or other symbol) of your input text as "relevant" or not, and train any neural network architecture which is good for tagging on this data. Specifically, I would look into architectures for POS tagging, because they are very well studied. Typically, it is BiLSTM, maybe with a CRF head. More modern models are based on pretrained contextual word embeddings, such as BERT (maybe, you won't even need to fine tune them - just use it as a feature extractor, and add a BiLSTM on top). If you want a more lightweight model, you can consider a CNN over pretrained and fixed word embeddings.

One final parameter you should time playing with is the threshold for classifying the word as relevant - maybe, the default one, 0.5, is not the best choice. Maybe, instead of keeping all the tokens with probability-of-being-important higher than 0.5, you would like to keep the top k tokens, where k is fixed or is some percentage of the whole text.

Of course, more specific recommendations would be dataset-specific, so if you could share your dataset, it would be a great help.